# Copying OS X account settings to a new user account

Tags: macos, user-accounts, osx-tiger

I accidentally renamed the username of my account on my Mac (running OS X 10.4.11) and tried renaming back to what it was but now I have two accounts (the one that I want to use which has all my preferences, applications, mail boxes, etc., and the new one).

Is it possible to copy my settings from my original account into this new username?  When I open my computer, it defaults to this new account, and I cannot gain access to all my work documents, mail settings, etc.

Comment: It's easier to do what Kio suggests than trying to mesh the accounts. Nuke the new account from orbit and use the old one.

Answer (score 4):

In System Preferences find Accounts and click the Login Options button. You've turned on Automatic Login for the new account name. Switch it to your old account or turn it off all together.

Also from the same Accounts preference pane, you can highlight the offending user and click the minus button below the user list to delete that user. You'll be given a few options on what to do with the left over user folder (all those Apple defaults you spoke of). Deletion should be fine if there's nothing important in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

If you are auto-logging in as the wrong user goto System Preferences > Accounts and turn off auto login.

If you renamed your user account name then Apple has good documentation on how to fix this.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428

They work.  I've done this successfully twice.

Oh, and please backup, backup, and backup again.